Limited count of draggable rows
I have a JSP project using SpreadJS 17.0, and when I try to drag and select data from the spread, only under a certain number of row data are selected - around 2,600 rows.
To set lock on some columns, I used 'Protection' option of SpreadJS and set up some details as follow.
const defaultSpreadOptions = {tabStripPosition: 1,tabStripVisible: false,tabEditable: false,newTabVisible: false,tabNavigationVisible: false,allowUserResize: true,allowUserZoom: false,showHorizontalScrollbar: false,showVerticalScrollbar: true,allowContextMenu: true};

const defaultProtectionOptions = {allowEditCells: false,allowEditObjects: false,allowSelectLockedCells: true,allowSelectUnlockedCells: true,allowSort: true,allowFilter: true,allowResizeRows: false,allowResizeColumns: false,allowDragInsertRows: false,allowDragInsertColumns: false,allowInsertRows: false,allowInsertColumns: false,allowDeleteRows: false,allowDeleteColumns: false,allowOutlineRows: false,allowOutlineColumns: false};

const defaultSheetOptions = {rowHeaderVisible: true,scrollbarMaxAlign: true,scrollbarShowMax: false,scrollIgnoreHidden: false,allowCellOverflow: false}

I removed the 'Protection' option from the page but still it's not working so I cannot tell whether the protection option is causing a problem.
All the other pages that initially didn't have 'Protection' options are working fine, but the protected pages aren't draggable more than 2,600 rows.
Are there any more options I should set up or the ones that should be removed?
Please, any suggestions would be grateful.

It sounds like you're encountering a limitation with SpreadJS 17.0 when dragging and selecting data beyond 2,600 rows. Here are a few suggestions to troubleshoot and potentially resolve the issue:

Check for Updates: Ensure you're using the latest version of SpreadJS 17.0, as updates often include bug fixes and performance improvements.
Optimize Protection Settings: Review your protection settings to ensure they're not overly restrictive. You might want to experiment with different combinations of protection options to see if any changes improve performance.
Performance Settings: Adjust performance-related settings in SpreadJS, such as enabling hardware acceleration or tweaking memory allocation, to see if it helps with handling larger datasets.
Event Handling: Ensure that event handlers for drag-and-drop operations are optimized and not causing performance bottlenecks.
Consult Documentation: Refer to the SpreadJS documentation and release notes for any specific guidance on handling large datasets and performance optimization.
Community Support: Contact the SpreadJS community or support forums for additional insights and potential solutions from other users who might have faced similar issues.
If these suggestions don't resolve the issue, a different approach or tool for handling large datasets in your project might be worth considering. Let me know if you need more detailed guidance on these steps!
